# Performs form action even out of the form

Tags: php

Hi having a problem with this code even if i clicked on cancel it will still proceed to use the action of my form even though the **CANCEL** button is not part of the **form**, Would appreciate any help.

Here is the code.

```
      <form method="post" action="input_enroll.php" >
            <div id="overlay1">

                <div>
                    <h1> Enter Educational Level Entry</h1>
                <input type="text" name="level" >
            <input type="submit"   value="Proceed To Enroll" '>
                    </form>
                <input type="submit"   value="Cancel" onclick='overlay()'>
                </div>
            </div>
```

EDIT: Any suggestions what would be a better idea? I'm thinking putting the **cancel** outside the div.

Comment: Once submitted and the HTTP process is starting the only way you can cancel is restating apache, let scripts finish or a timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having form started, then divs started, then form closed..start form after divs..

as your markup is not correct, browsers will change it as thier parser suggest,

In chrome `</form>` tag is postponed after `</div>`s..

```
        <div id="overlay1">
            <div>
            <form method="post" action="input_enroll.php" >
                <h1> Enter Educational Level Entry</h1>
                <input type="text" name="level" />
                <input type="submit"   value="Proceed To Enroll" />
            </form>
            <input type="submit" value="Cancel" onclick='overlay()' />
            </div>
        </div>
```